# Дисплей nokia 1100

Tags: железо

Слышал что можно подсоединить дисплей от nokia 1100 и программировать. Можете показать каким способом подключить к компьютеру.

Answer (score 2):

[@Егор](/users/2399/%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80), проще всего - подключить к Arduino (схема подключения очень простая) и с него рулить (есть готовые библиотеки именно под этот экранчик). Гуглите "arduino nokia 1100" - найдете все, что нужно.

Если вы хотите управлять экранчиком с компьютера, то все как написано выше, только Arduino (или любой аналог с usb на борту) подключается к компьютеру через usb и выполняет роль посредника: слушает поступающие по usb команды и рулит экраном.

Слать команды на Arduino можно используя любой язык программирования, способный работать с COM-портом. Для быстрого старта без заморочек можно взять Processing.